# How to Bind to TextBox Background color

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a text box for user to enter 6 character hex color value, a validator & a converter attached to it. Up to here, everything works fine. But I want to bind a textbox's `Background` color to the color specified by the text box (`ElementName`s `Background` & `Foreground`), and it does not seem to work.

When I debug/step through the code, the value seems like is always `""`

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="Background" Canvas.Left="328" Canvas.Top="33" Height="23" Width="60">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Background">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:ColorValidator Property="Background" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converters:ColorConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<TextBlock Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="12" Text="Foreground" />
<TextBox x:Name="Foreground" Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="33" Height="23" Width="60">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Foreground">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:ColorValidator Property="Foreground" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converters:ColorConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<!-- in this example I used the converter used in the TextBox & another converter that converts a string to color -->
<TextBox ... 
    Background="{Binding ElementName=Background, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" 
    Foreground="{Binding ElementName=Foreground, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource stringToColorConverter}}" />
```

**Converters**

```
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            string entry = ((Color)value).ToString();
            return entry.Substring(3); 
        } catch (Exception) {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string entry = (string)value;
        Validators.ColorValidator validator = new Validators.ColorValidator();
        if (!validator.Validate(entry, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).IsValid) {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        return (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF" + entry);
    }
}

class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string entry = (string)value;
        Validators.ColorValidator validator = new Validators.ColorValidator();
        if (!validator.Validate(entry, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).IsValid)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        return (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF" + entry);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, thus a comment, but maybe the problem is, that TextBox.Background etc all need a Brush, not a Color.

Comment: A better title would surely help to collect appropriate attention.

Comment: As Jens said, try converting to a Brush rather than Color

Comment: You should also avoid using try/catch blocks to ignore all errors. If you didn't just return `Binding.DoNothing` or added logging, you would have seen cause of the errors.

Comment: Or you can just breakpoint in at the Binding.DoNothing and $exception will show up at the locals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone saying that you need a brush and not a color is right.

**Solution:** Create another converter that returns a SolidColorBrush and you will be golden.

Answer (score -1):

This May help who works in Asp.net technology. Which is used to set the Forecolor and Backcolor of the Textbox when bind the value of Textbox inside GridView.  I am using this in .Net Version 4.6, I hope it support for other versions too.. Thank You

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewStatus"  runat="server">
                 <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
                           <ItemTemplate>      
                              <asp:Label ID="lbljobstatusAll" runat="server" 
    Text="<%#Eval("Status")  %>"  ForeColor='<%# Eval("Status").ToString().Contains("Yes") ? System.Drawing.Color.Green : System.Drawing.Color.Blue %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The question is about WPF.